# Utilizar a propriedade R1C1

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Quero usar a propriedade `Range.Formula R1C1` num formulário de cópia de cheque para preenchimento automático de cheque nominal. Como poderia usar esta propriedade com esse fim?

Encontrei um código descrito da seguinte forma:

```
Sub Para()
'
' Para Macro
' Macro gravada em 4/9/2006 por Fundação  Fé e Alegria
'
'
Range("D7:J14").Select

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-9]C"

Range("D15:
```

Porem não entendi.

Answer (score 3):

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 serve para você escrever na célula selecionada. Se você faz:

```
Range("D7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "abc"
```

a macro seleciona a célula D7 e escreve `abc` nela.

No seu exemplo você selecionou várias linhas e colunas, entretanto apenas escreveu na primeira delas, o D7.

Sua macro faz com que o conteúdo da célula seja uma fórmula que simplesmente replica o conteúdo de outra célula, por causa do `=` seguido de uma posição relativa. A posição relativa que você escreveu foi `R[-9]C` que diz que o endereço da outra célula é 9 linhas e menos que a atual, na mesma coluna. `R` é uma abreviação de ROW, que significa linha. `C` é uma abreviação de COLUMN que significa coluna.

9 linhas a menos provavelmente vai causar um comportamento não desejado, já que você está na linha 7.

Calcule corretamente o valor relativo da célula D7 e substitua na sua macro. Além disso, pode trocar o `Range("D7:J14").Select` por `Range("D7").Select`, já que não está fazendo diferença. Se sua intenção é escrever em todos os campos desse range, refaça sua macro para copiar célula por célula. Selecionar um range tem outras utilidades como por exemplo mesclar tais células.

Outro exemplo de cálculo de célula relativa: `R[-1]C[-2]`, se refere a uma linha a menos e duas colunas a menos.